# Question about a proof in Lang's undergraduate analysis

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

[image]

This is from page 580 of Lang's undergraduate analysis (2nd edition).

I have difficulty in understanding the proof, hope that someone here can enlighten me.

My questions are:

i)  On line 5 of the proof, why is it true that the boundary of $A$ equals the boundary of the closure of $A$?

ii) Why do we need this fact in this proof?

Thank you in advance for taking time to answer my question.

PS: According to Lang, a set is said to be admissible if it is bounded and its boundary is a negligible set.

A set $S$ is said to be negligible if for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists a finite number of rectangles the sum of whose volumes are less that $\epsilon$ and their union covers $S$. This is usually called Jordan content 0.